# Date Order By DESC and 'header_id ' Group By in codeIgniter Query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, codeigniter-3

I need a query, `receive_date` descending order also have `header_id` group by from table messages. Where join `message_headers` table `status = 0`.

```
    $this->db->select('me.*, mh.*,max(me.receive_date) as receive_date');
    $this->db->from('messages as me');
    $this->db->join('message_headers as mh', 'em.header_id = eh.id');
    $this->db->where('me.account_id',1); 
    $this->db->where('mh.status', 0);
    $this->db->order_by('receive_date', 'DESC');
    $this->db->group_by('me.header_id');
    $message = $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

output not show `desc` order. some broke down. some right way.

Comment: use echo $this->db->last_query() to debug your mysql query.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->select('me.*, mh.*,max(me.receive_date) as receive_date');
$this->db->from('messages as me');
$this->db->join('message_headers as mh', 'me.header_id = mh.id');
$this->db->where('me.account_id',1); 
$this->db->where('mh.status', 0);
$this->db->group_by('me.header_id');
$this->db->order_by('receive_date', 'DESC');
$message = $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

Comment: I do this . It's Not give what i want

Comment: The column receive_date may be conflicting

Answer (score 0):

Use `STR_TO_DATE` for date format.

```
$this->db->select('me.*, mh.*, MAX(STR_TO_DATE(me.receive_date, '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s')) as receive_date');
$this->db->from('messages as me');
$this->db->join('message_headers as mh', 'em.header_id = eh.id');
$this->db->where('me.account_id',1); 
$this->db->where('mh.status', 0);
$this->db->order_by('receive_date', 'DESC');
$this->db->group_by('me.header_id');
$message = $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

Comment: Thank you @DelwarSumon . It's Worked. Cause Table Column have string.